# Как правильно написать header(location..)

Tags: javascript, header, alert, location

помогите пожалуйста как правильно изменить alert на header("location: /websites/order/order-access.php");

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 //E-mail Ajax Send
 $("#order-form").submit(function() { //Change
  var th = $(this);
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../php/order-mail.php", //Change
   data: th.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
   alert("Вы успешно отправили заявку");
   setTimeout(function() {
    // Done Functions
    th.trigger("reset");
   }, 1000);
  });
  return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> header("*");

Это из PHP?

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```